# bxSlider cuts off slide viewing mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mobile, bxslider

I am using `bxSlider` and it's working great...I'm having a slight issue with some functionality...when I view the slideshow on mobile it shows 1.5...basically one full slide and then part of the next one. In the code, I have `minSlides` set to 1 and `maxSlides` set to 3...what I'd like to do is have `bxSlider` display a particular `li` only if the entire `li` will fit on the screen. For example, my div's are 300px wide, in order to show two of them your screen size would have to be at least 600px wide...is that possible?

I created a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/785gcrnp/.

The example page is: http://joshrodg.com/hallmark/ - all the way on the bottom in the dark area where it says "Latest Media".

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: I found a solution (http://jsfiddle.net/bvec9n9r/) that works but you have to refresh the page every time you resize the page...which works ok, but with an iPad or something that can change it's screen resolution as you turn it, it would be better if I could just resize the browser to see the changes...is there a way to adjust this code so it can function that way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend of mine helped me get this working!

I have updated the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/785gcrnp/1/

```
var sm = 20;
var podcastSlider;

function podcastSettings() {
    var minmax;
    var win=$(window).width();

      if(win > 960) {
        minmax=3;
        var sw = 300;
      } else if(win > 660) {
        minmax=2;
        var sw = 300;
      } else {
        minmax=1;
        var sw = 480;
      }

      var sliderSettings={
        adaptiveHeight: true,
        infiniteLoop: false,
        maxSlides: minmax,
        mode: 'horizontal',
        nextSelector: '.next',
        nextText: 'Next',
        pager: false,
        prevSelector: '.prev',
        prevText: 'Prev',
        slideMargin: sm,
        slideWidth: sw
      };

      return sliderSettings;
    }

    $(window).resize(function() {
      podcastSlider.reloadSlider(podcastSettings());
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
      podcastSlider = $('.podcast').bxSlider(podcastSettings());
    });
```

This will center the slides and only show the amount of slides that will be fully visible without cutting anything off.

This is also responsive, so if I resize the browser everything will update as it should.

In addition, I specified a different width for smaller screens.

I hope this helps someone else!

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: Made one more minor change this morning...changed the ``$(document).ready(function()`` to ``$(window).load(function()`` because the bottom part of my li's were getting cut off.

Answer (score 0):

Nice, looks like you've made some good progress. There is a way you can wrap your current code in a function and call it when the window resizes or orientation changes.

Here's what it would look like wrapped in a function:

```
function adjustSlider(){
    var sw = 200;
    var sm = 20;
    var ms = Math.floor($('#nocrop').width() / (sw + sm));
    $('#nocrop .bxslider').bxSlider({
        pager: false,
        slideWidth: sw,
        slideMargin: sm,
        maxSlides: ms > 1 ? ms : 1,
    });
}
```

Then, we need to call this function when the document first loads, otherwise your calculations will only get used when the window resizes:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    adjustSlider();
});
```

Then, we add a window resize event. I place the call to the adjustSlider fucntion inside a timer so it helps if the window is resized a bunch within a short amount of time. We can also add the onorientationchange event in here too that makes the same call. Orientation changes have their own delays built in and this event doesn't fire off as frequently as window resize, so I didn't put this in a timer.

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        adjustSlider();
    }, 250);
});

window.onorientationchange = function(event){
    adjustSlider();
}
```

250 ms for the timer might be a little high, feel free to adjust this. It still feels pretty weighty to me when resizing the panes on jsfiddle. This could be due to how the javascript is being run inside jsfiddle, or it could have something to do with the way this slider is handling having it's properties set. It will show best on your actual site, so do some testing there to be sure speed and performance don't become an issue with this. Let me know how it goes!

Also, here is a working jsfiddle for an example of how it all looks when put together: http://jsfiddle.net/sm1215/0517f76w/4/

edit: words, woops also placed the onorientationchange inside the resize event, which wouldn't work. This is fixed and I've updated the fiddle.

Comment: Close! This is working...when I have a large browser the code displays three ``li's``, then it goes down to one depending on the size of the browser - which is awesome! But...when I try to go from a small browser (where it's only displaying one to start off with) and go to a large browser I still only see one ``li``...any ideas?

Comment: Hmm, I see. I noticed the bxwrapper div was correctly adjusting it's max-width when scaled down, but wouldn't change to a larger value when the window was expanded like you said. One interesting thing though, your slider was still moving the correct number of slides as if the wrapper were the correct size. Like if you were to click Next, the slider would jump 3 slides instead of just 1, even though it was only wide enough to display one. 

Anyway you would mind putting the code back on your site just to poke around a bit more? It functions a bit differently than the jsfiddle

Comment: Thinking we could try calling $('.podcast').reloadSlider(); at the bottom of adjustSlider()

Updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/sm1215/0517f76w/5/

Comment: The reload actually stopped it from working, but I did add the code back to: http://joshrodg.com/hallmark/

Comment: The posts are changing when the window resizes...it starts with "Compassion", then when it gets smaller that becomes "Motives" (unless you refresh the page)

Comment: Ah I see, ok. I also see some things that might need some re-arranging. The variables "sw", "sm", and "ms" got moved outside of the bxSlider function and so these aren't getting recalculated when the window resizes - which leaves the slider at the set measurements from when it is first initialized. Also, it might be good to separate bxSlider into 2 different types of calls. It seems when it is adjusted on resize, it is re-adding things like nextSelect and prevSelector multiple times. These should only be created on first page load.